# building a bytes message in C++

Tags: c++

*edit: this project is University assignment, in the specifications were told to build the message with short in the beginning. otherwise I would use string a long time before. I also added sendBytes function to the code attached.*

I'm trying to build server-client project. I've written the server in Java and the client in C++.
the message server expects to receive is a bytes array, in the format of (short<string ending with'\0'><string ending with \0>). the decoder on server side seems to work fine.

However I'm struggling with building the proper message in C++.
I know there is no byte object in C++, and every object can be represented as bytes array. But I still can't send the right message.

For example I received from user's keyboard the following command:
"LOGIN jack asd123" and I want to convert the message so the server will receive:
(2 bytes representing opcode short 3)(bytes representing string - jack\0)(bytes representing string -asd123\0).

here is something I tried to write, inside ConnectionHandler.cpp. I guess the focus should be on sendCommand..

```
bool ConnectionHandler::sendCommand(string &cmd, char delimiter) {
   vector<string> parsed = stringSplit(cmd); //the ith value in vector is the ith word in the cmd
   short op = getOP(parsed[0])
   bool result = sendBytes(op+parsed[1]+'\0'+parsed[2]+'\0');
   if (!result)
       return false;
   return sendBytes(&delimiter, 1);
}


// Close down the connection properly.
void ConnectionHandler::close() {
   try {
       socket_.close();
   } catch (...) {
       cout << "closing failed: connection already closed" << endl;
   }
}

vector<string> ConnectionHandler::stringSplit(string &s) {
   // parsing the user's message to vector of strings
   string delimiter = " ";
   vector<string> ans;
   size_t pos = 0;
   string token;
   while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
       token = s.substr(0, pos);
       ans.push_back(token);
       s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
   }
   ans.push_back(s);
   return ans;
}

short ConnectionHandler::getOP(basic_string<char> &basicString) {
   if (basicString == "ADMINREG") return 1;
   if (basicString == "STUDENTREG") return 2;
   if (basicString == "LOGIN") return 3;
   if (basicString == "LOGOUT") return 4;
   if (basicString == "COURSEREG") return 5;
   if (basicString == "KDAMCHECK") return 6;
   if (basicString == "COURSESTAT") return 7;
   if (basicString == "STUDENTSTAT") return 8;
   if (basicString == "ISREGISTERED") return 9;
   if (basicString == "UNREGISTER") return 10;
   if (basicString == "MYCOURSES") return 11;

   return 0;

bool ConnectionHandler::sendBytes(const char bytes[], int bytesToWrite) {
   int tmp = 0;
   boost::system::error_code error;
   try {
       while (!error && bytesToWrite > tmp) {
           tmp += socket_.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(bytes + tmp, bytesToWrite - tmp), error);
       }
       if (error)
           throw boost::system::system_error(error);
   } catch (exception &e) {
       cerr << "recv failed (Error: " << e.what() << ')' << endl;
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

however it obviously doesn't work...

***How do I build the proper message?***

any guidance would be super helpful.

Thank you

Comment: You haven't shown sendBytes, but its argument is the result of doing _arithmetic_ on a `short`. Specifically addition. The `+` operator doesn't mean concatenation, unless perhaps the first argument is an object which overloads it. So, again, not a `short`.

Comment: `op+parsed[1]+'\0'+parsed[2]+'\0'` is not going to work. If `sendBytes` takes a `std::string` you need to change it to `std::to_string(op)+parsed[1]+'\0'+parsed[2]+'\0'`.